# Converting a fetch-based function to async that previously returned a promise

Tags: javascript

I have a `super_fetch` function that "extends" `fetch()` by performing a user session check before running `fetch`:

```
function super_fetch() {
    checkUserSessionIsStillValid(); // Check if the user can interact

    return fetch(...arguments); // Create the fetch call
}
```

`checkUserSessionIsStillValid()` makes a `fetch` of its own and `.then()` processes the result and displays an error on the UI if the session is invalid. Technically it is not stopping the `super_fetch` from executing its `fetch` call, though.

I updated the `checkUserSessionIsStillValid` function to return a promise which will resolve to `true` or `false`. I reworked my function to take advantage of this:

```
async function super_fetch() {
    let isSessionValid = await checkUserSessionIsStillValid(); // Check if the user can interact

    if (!isSessionValid) { return false; } // Invalid session, don't pull data

    return fetch(...arguments); // Create the fetch call
}
```

Now my issue is that by doing this, I change the nature of the returned value of `super_fetch` from a `Promise` containing a `Response`, to… *something else*, meaning that things like `super_fetch(url, args).then((response) => response.json())` throw errors.

I am uncertain of what exactly that "something else" is, and how I can solve for it at the function definition level, since I cannot go in and edit every single `super_fetch` call in my code base.

My understanding of `async`/`await` is still limited but if you know what is causing this and how I can resolve it (either by example or by specific documentation links), I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you save response from `fetch` inside of that function and call also `.json()` on that data and then simply return data ?

Comment: Thats not the ideal way to check the user session in real application, it should handle from sockets through backend programming.

Comment: @DominikMatis It's not always JSON that's being returned. Your idea isn't bad by any means but that would require me to change my function call across the entire code base.

Comment: `return checkUserSessionIsStillValid().then(result => if (result) { return fetch(...arguments); } else { return Promise.reject(); })`

Comment: Then I'd try `let response = await fetch(...); return response;` because `async` always returns Promise, even if you return just a number, or maybe `return await fetch(...)` would also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `throw` instead of `return false;` that way `super_fetch(...).then` will not be called, you can make it throw real error so catch will work like the one on fetch.

```
async function super_fetch() {
    let isSessionValid = await checkUserSessionIsStillValid();

    if (!isSessionValid) {
       throw new Error('Invalid session');
    }

    return fetch(...arguments);
}
```

the other solution if you need `then` and `json()`

```
async function super_fetch() {
    let isSessionValid = await checkUserSessionIsStillValid();

    if (!isSessionValid) {
       return {
           json: () => ({error: 'Invalid Session'})
       };
    }

    return fetch(...arguments);
}
```

and as reference:

```
function super_fetch() {
   return fetch(...arguments);
}

async function super_fetch() {
   return fetch(...arguments);
}
```

both are exactly the same. If `async` function return promise it will be the result, the only difference is that if you return value it will be wrapped in promise (and you can use await to stop the function) so:

```
async function super_fetch() {
    let isSessionValid = await checkUserSessionIsStillValid();

    if (!isSessionValid) {
       return false;
    }

    return fetch(...arguments);
}
```

is the same as:

```
function super_fetch() {
    var args = arguments;
    checkUserSessionIsStillValid().then((isSessionValid) => {
        if (!isSessionValid) {
            return false;
        }
        return fetch(...args);
    });
}
```

or simpler example:

```
function super_fetch() {
    if (!isSessionValid) {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    }
    return fetch(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: If there is no error, the returned value is not usable by my code base's calls. My issue is with successful returns, not errors.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen check this example https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/PoYNRLy?editors=0011 you have error when session is invalid because you're returning `false`, this have nothing to do with `async` and that you return call to `fetch`. Just remove you session code and you will see that your super_fetch will work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, makes a lot more sense to me now! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

All async functions are synonymous with Promises. You can use `Promise.reject()` within the async function to skip the `.then` and go to `.catch`

```
async function super_fetch() {
    let isSessionValid = await checkUserSessionIsStillValid(); // Check if the user can interact

    if (!isSessionValid) { return Promise.reject("Session is Not Valid"); } // Invalid session, don't pull data

    return fetch(...arguments); // Create the fetch call
}

super_fetch(url, args).then((response) => response.json()).catch(console.error)
```

---

### Example:

```js
async function demo() {
  return Promise.reject("whatever");
}

demo().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I have a better understanding of `async`'s behaviour now. Appreciate it!